# Deleting and restoring divs toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a switch between a div being deleted and it being restored based on an Event trigger. I am using jquery. How do i do that using .click event?

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve, can you attempt to explain it more clearly. It would help to explain step by step the user process and what happens at each stage

Comment: Hi kennvbrian, do you have any code? Also, do you actually need to delete or just show/hide?

Comment: how can you restore a deleted div? do you mean 'hide' and 'show'?

Comment: @kennvbrian, do you want anything like this http://jsfiddle.net/qag14awb/

Comment: I was trying to create this from scratch. The div would need to be deleted then another (div) create with some moderate changes in its styling and an image.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple lets say you will have 2 divs.

use this in in JS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

          $("#div1").hide();
          $("#div2").hide();


                    $('#button1').click(function() {
                        $("#div1").show();
                        $("#div2").hide();

                    });

                    $('#button2').click(function() {
                        $("#div1").hide();
                        $("#div2").show();

                    });


                });
```

And HTML

```
<button id="button1" >Show Div1 </button> 
<button id="button2" >Show Div2 </button> 

<br><br>

    <div id="div1" ><h1> Hello </h1></div>
    <div id="div2" > <h1> Bye </h1></div>
```

See a live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ptqdrr8t/1/

Comment: Thanks. Not what I wanted but its what I'll use.

Comment: @kennvbrian Can you please mark my answer as accepted? I  need to go up  :$ so that i can comment:P Thank you very much! and ->  `The div would need to be deleted then another (div) create with some moderate changes in its styling and an image` -> i can do that for you add me on skype: `missessalima` then we will discuss

Comment: @SSD: This isn't a dating website, you probably shouldn't be broadcasting your skype id

Comment: @musefan: At least not without a profile picture you mean :p

Answer (score 0):

You can find a div and use it with jQuery to move it and also change the styling/content/classnames etc. But it's not always best for performance, you can also consider to show/hide the div instead as was suggested earlier.

An example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/web_nfo/57x4agL7/

Html:

```
<div id="removedItems"></div>
<div class="item">
    <h3>Item1</h3>
    <span class="remove">Remove</span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item span.remove').click(function(){
        // Find the item
        var $item = $(this).parent();

        // You can change the original item
        $item
        .addClass('removed')
        .find('h3').append('<span>[removed]</span>');

        // Move the item
        $('#removedItems').append( $item );
    });
});
```

Or if you are looking for another way (to really 'remove' the item first) you can store the whole $item object in an array, and use it later on to re-create something. Maybe something like this?

```
var history = [];
$('.item span.remove').click(function{
    var $item = $(this);

    history.push( $item );
    $item.remove();
});
```

If you are creating an 'undo' function you also have to remember the position of the item (before it was removed) to put it back at the correct spot.